# React native assign values after selecting value from DateRangePicker

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I want to set value of an array after selecting a value from the drop down but the issue is it is inside a return statement

```
 else if(item.type== 4){
    console.log("QueryArr"+queryArr)
      return(
        <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
      <DateRangePicker
      onChange={this.setDates,queryObj = {"fieldId":item.compareToFieldId,"value":startDate,"value1":"","queryOperator":item.operator}, queryArr.concat(queryObj)}
      endDate={endDate}
      startDate={startDate}
      displayedDate={displayedDate}
      range
    >
```

Already Tried : If I write like above, it gives error.
I create a separate file, the Date Range Picker doesnt show up.
I write return statement inside a func and call it before assigning values to variables, that doesnt show the control either.
Please suggest any solution if any. Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe is typo? this.setDates,queryObj, you use comma after setDates and before queryOBj

Comment: There is a comma as I have written above.